# Can SharePoint 2013 be configured & Installed without connecting to Active Directory

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, active-directory, installation, configuration

We want to build a public facing web site using SharePoint 2013 . but as the public facing web site will be accessed by public users, so can we configure and install the SharePoint server 2013  , without the need to connecting it to Active directory ? . Or using Active directory is mandatory for SharePoint 2013 installation; regardless of whether we want to create a web application inside it which is designed for anonymous users only.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 requires Active Directory and does not support production deployments on Active Directory Domain Controllers.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2764086

Comment: can you explain what do u mean by "and does not support production deployments on Active Directory Domain Controllers." . do u mean that i can not install sharepoint on production inside the same server where the AD is installed?

Comment: Correct, it is not supported to deploy SharePoint to a server where the AD DS role is also deployed.

Comment: Could you also explain why?

Comment: There are a couple reasons off the top of my head I can think of. For one, SharePoint Foundation cannot be configured without them if you want to leverage Search (as you must use the Config Wizard). Likely the more important one, Microsoft no longer wanted to test for the scenario and/or the scenario generated an inordinate amount of support requests to Microsoft. Likely the same with installing SharePoint on a DC.

Answer (score 2):

There are to choices:

- install Active Directory on one of your SharePoint farm servers. It will be your separate AD forest
- Create SharePoint Application pool with classic authentication in PowerShell without the need to connect to AD:

`New-SPWebApplication -Name "Contoso Internet Site" -ApplicationPool "ContosoAppPool" -AuthenticationMethod "NTLM" -ApplicationPoolAccount (Get-SPManagedAccount "CONTOSO\jdoe") -Port 80 -URL "https://www.contoso.com`"

[Here is more info on this topic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276326.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use the Local Users on the server, but I wouldn't recommend it. I have done this for 2007, and it's a pain to have a lot of users on one box. It requires a lot of micro-management. You can use the `servername\localuseraccount` as theirusername. Try following [this link](http://techs.studyhorror.com/sharepoint-2013-create-new-farm-admin-using-local-user-accounts-i-86) to set it up.

Comment: so i can install & work with SP on production without having to connect it to AD ?

Comment: You may need to use AD for the install, but you can use the user accounts on the local server. Follow that link so help you set it up. Again, I do not recommend this for production, but it is possible! I recommend FBA if you want to have external users connect to your SharePoint env.

Comment: I would try the install without AD and use machine accounts. I know it's not supported, but I think it's possible (but haven't tried it personally).

Answer (score 0):

Well as I understood you would like to use SharePoint for a "Public Facing web site" so users should not be on AD because this has got licensing costs.

Really Trevor is right, for installation and all the service accounts needed for it you need an AD, but later you can use other repositories for keeping users.

Try to use OpenLdap and ADFS or other server like ThinkTecture to have the Authentication and the source for the userProfile Services. Also Remember you need claims authentication configuration web app and site collection.

Thanks